# Knowing from which machines a Spark task is reading its shuffle data

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running an experiment in a Spark cluster where some of the machines are
highly loaded with CPU, memory and network consuming process ( let's call
them straggler machines ).

Obviously the tasks of these machines take longer to execute than in other
nodes of the cluster. However I've noticed that the tasks that fetch shuffle
data from these "straggler machines" are also delayed with long Read Shuffle
Data phases.

Is there anyway of knowing from which machines a task is reading its shuffle
data?. Something like node1 is reading its shuffle data from [node2,node3
and node4]?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This information is stored in the [MapStatus](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/MapStatus.scala) internally. I'm not sure it's exposed in any way. This is partition-to-partition, and with many small partitions there will be pairs of partitions with no communication. But node-to-node I think in a typical shuffle every node gets some data from every other node.